# instruction screen ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

Any help please, I'am trying to use welcome screen in my app that shows instruction for the first time only. iam using NSuserDefultes 
in the tutorial view controller

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults;
defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
    [defaults synchronize];
```

In the app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

What is the wrong in this code?

Comment: What is the problem you're facing now? The instructions screen is not showing?

Comment: post some code or describe your question properly

Comment: showing every time i open the application but i need it  only one time

Comment: Where do you show your message?

Comment: Is that the Default storyboard or image you in the Xcode project?

Comment: when you download app from store you show at first time toutrial screen that show how your app will do you can skip it and it will not appear next time at all .
iam trying to do that but every time i open my app it shows toutrial screen what is the problem in my code ? Pratik Jamariya

Comment: storyboard @meaning-matters

Comment: @MonaAli follow [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/), and you should set `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];` when you finish your one time instruction

Comment: @PratikJamariya i already follow this tutorial and i make this pages only one time .. thank you for your help i wish you understand me

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand where every piece of your sample code is called, so I will try describe a general way to achieve that.

Before showing the tutorial, you should check whether it is the first launch or not, like this:

```
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
    [self displayTutorial];
```

`displayTutorial` is a method that presents the tutorial's view controller.

Inside the `viewDidLoad` of your tutorial view controller, set that boolean to true like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

That way, the tutorial view controller will be displayed only once.

Comment: what about app delegate.m ??

Comment: If you followed the way described here you won't need to put anything in the app delegate.

Answer (score 0):

The main/default storyboard you select in the app's .plist file always shows up when the app starts. You can't make that conditional.

If you want some conditional launch screen, you must implement that yourself, after the default launch screen disappears, like [Moe Abdul-Hameed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44472181/1971013) suggests.